# Linking elasticsearch db and mongodb to spring boot application using docker-compose giving issues

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I have a spring boot application which uses elasticsearch db and mongodb. I want to dockerize this on a docker-container for which I have written a docker-compose yml file which is given below

```
version : "3"
services:
  eswmongodb:
   image: mongo:latest
   container_name: mongocont
   ports:
    - "27017:27017"

  elasticsearch:
   image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.3
   container_name: elasticsearch
   environment:
    - node.name=elasticsearch
    - discovery.type=single-node
    - cluster.name=docker-cluster
   ports:
    - "9200:9200"
    - "9300:9300"


 esw:
  image: esw
  container_name: eswrapper
  ports:
    - "8071:8071"
  links:
    - elasticsearch
    - eswmongodb
```

Only mongodb is getting connected with the spring boot application and I am able to access that but when I am hitting an api which uses a elasticsearch. I get an error as

Occurred with exception:[Connection refused]

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

I have supplied the necessary information in application.properties file.

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-node=elasticsearch:9200
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=docker-cluster
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://eswmongodb:27017/esw
```

Any thoughts why elasticsearch is not able to get connected.
I have seen earlier answers provided in stack-overflow but the issue still persists.

All container are showing running.

Also tried `spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes` this property but this becomes disable so I went with `spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-node`.

I have also added the actual exception present in logs when I hit an api endpoint which uses elastic search for further help if required.

```
2022-01-04 13:44:45,354 | ERROR | TxId=1641303885129000010435 | 
IndexOperationsImpl.createIndexWithCustomSettingAndMapping:62 | 
Exception Occurred with exception:[Connection refused]

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at 

org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.
extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:849)

at  org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.
performRequest(RestClient.java:259)

at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.
performRequest(RestClient.java:246)
```

Some logs of elasticsearch container when hitting docker-compose logs elasticsearch

```
Attaching to elasticsearch
elasticsearch    | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-01- 
04T16:03:59,187Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", 
"cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "elasticsearch", 
"message": "version[7.9.3], pid[7], 
[default/docker/c4138e51121ef06a6404866cddc601906fe5c868/2020 
10-16T13:34:25.304557Z], OS[Linux/5.10.25-linuxkit/aarch64], 
JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/15/15+36-1562]" }
elasticsearch    | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-01- 
04T16:03:59,189Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", 
"cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "elasticsearch", 
"message": "JVM home [/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk]" }
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of "docker-compose logs elasticsearch" to your question? If there was error in the log, you can paste just the error will do.

Comment: That smells like a dead elastic container right after start.

Comment: `links:` is an obsolete and unnecessary Compose option, and it might interfere with the networking setup.  Does removing the `links:` block (or changing it to `depends_on:`) help?  Is the application starting up before Elasticsearch is available?

Comment: yes application is running but only with mongodb, if I hit for an api which uses elastic search it says connection refused

Comment: @gohm, I have the added the exception which is coming in the logs.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I have tried with depends_on: same error is coming, working for mongodb but not with elastic-search

Comment: @Zeitounator, the container in which elastic-search db is running is not getting exited, so I don't see any error there. It is up and shows running but doesn't connect and gives connection refused

Comment: You should add this info to your question as well as the logs from your elastic container.

Comment: @Zeitounator updated

Comment: You need to paste the output of "docker-compose logs elasticsearch"

Comment: @gohm'c, there are lot of logs. so added some part in the question.

Comment: First, thoroughly examine the output of your Elastic container (especially at startup) for any clue on its networking (not only for "errors").

If everything is ok there, try to widen up for where your node will accept connections at: add the network.host=0.0.0.0 to your environment options.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by providing `spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes` in application.yml instead of application.properties file. It may sound strange but don't know why it is disabled in properties file but works in yml file as provided below.

```
spring:
  data:
    elasticsearch:
      cluster-name: docker-cluster
      cluster-nodes: elasticsearch:9200
```

Anyway thanks for providing suggestions in comment section of the question